# How to disable Virtualizing for lisbox item Wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, checkbox, listbox

I am not able to disable the Virtualizing property under VirtualizingStackPanel  for listbox .I am only getting VirtualizationMode property.
Actually i need to get checkbox element under listbox.Tried several methods but most appropriate ans i got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417086/wp8not-able-to-get-checkbox-in-listbox/28430618#28430618)
but i was getting ItemContainerGenerator as null.
After more rnd i found that i need to set IsVirtualizing=false to get the ItemContainerGenerator .
xaml is ::

```
<ListBox x:Name="my_list" Grid.Row="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <CheckBox x:Name="cbx_state"  Tag="{Binding}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txt_string" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="34" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I am not able to get VirtualizingStackPanel.isvertualing property.I was trying to get cbx_state.

Comment: Your question is you have to check the check boxes from c# code am I right?

Comment: yes tried one method.....but while using it ItemContainerGenerator coming as  null value and i found that it is due to isvertualing property set true...which i will have to set to false to get ItemContainerGenerator

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713365/itemcontainergenerator-containerfromitem-returns-null/16175021#16175021) it says to set VirtualizingStackPanel.isvertualing=false i am not able to get .isvertualing property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done in this manner i got check box checked from c#
In Page1.xaml:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PhoneApp3.Page1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
<ListBox x:Name="my_list" Height="200" Grid.Row="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <CheckBox x:Name="cbx_state"  Tag="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_string" Text="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="34" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

in page1.cs

```
namespace PhoneApp3
{
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String[] names = { "Virat", "Rohit", "Rahane", "Umesh", "Axar" };
        my_list.ItemsSource = names;
        this.Loaded += Page1_Loaded;
    }

    void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetItemsRecursive(my_list);
    }

    private void GetItemsRecursive(DependencyObject lb)
    {
        var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(lb);

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(lb, i);

            if (child is CheckBox) // specific/child control 
            {
                CheckBox targeted_element = (CheckBox)child;

                targeted_element.IsChecked = true;

                if (targeted_element.IsChecked == true)
                {

                    return;
                }
            }

            GetItemsRecursive(child);
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Arun.P it works as i wanted....i was trying from weeks thanks a lot . Just a bit change at DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(lb, i); instead of var child