# Windows Phone 8, finding a checkbox item inside listbox

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a checkbox inside a stackpanel inside a listbox. I need to set the visibility of that checkbox based on some logical operations, so I need to find that element in listbox.

I am using the following code to find the checkbox on my PageLoad, after the list`s dataSource has been set. 
But on this listboxItem i get a null value and a exception saying : reference is not a valid visual dependencyobject

```
private void searchListCheckBoxVisibility()
        //private void SearchList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ListBoxItem listItem = this.SearchList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(2) as ListBoxItem;
                CheckBox targetCheckBox = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<CheckBox>(listItem);
}
}
```

The following is my xaml :

```
Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox Margin="13,10,7,10" x:Name="SearchList" DoubleTap="SearchList_DoubleTap">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="searchListPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="340">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Name : " FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding User}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Project : " FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Project}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Status : " FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding On_OffBoarded}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Date : " FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DT_On_OffBoarded}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelines_TextBlock}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text=""/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox Width="60" 
                                      x:Name="user_Checkbox" 
                                      Content="" Tag="{Binding ID}" 
                                      Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                      Checked="user_Checkbox_Checked"
                                      Unchecked="user_Checkbox_UnChecked"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MSFTGuidelinesCheckBox}"
                                      IsChecked="False"

                                      />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

I am stuck at this issue for a while, and it has been getting onto my nerves now, Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `VisualTreeHelper` to find a control within your `Listbox` data template.

Reference: [How to access a specific item in a Listbox with DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181063/)