# How to find LongListMuliselector inside another ListBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I need to find the LongListMultiSelector inside ListBox .

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxName" Width="400">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Bewise:ExpanderControl x:Name="bewiseControl" HeaderText="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}" Width="400" >
                            <Bewise:ExpanderControl.ContentArea>
                                <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector ItemsSource="{Binding LstProdcuts}" x:Name="LongList">
                                    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate >
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel >
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  />

                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                                </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
                            </Bewise:ExpanderControl.ContentArea>

                        </Bewise:ExpanderControl>


                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

i need to access LongList inside ListBoxName.I needed this LongList to get the selected item and itemSource or to add item to the selecteditem of the list

Comment: ...What ar eyou trying to do?

Comment: Is that just to find the `LongListMultiselector`?

Comment: I want the LongList reference so that i can set/get its properties like EnforceIsSelectionEnabled or visibility etc

Comment: @user3207655: no. Don't access any element from the code-behind. There is absolutely no reason, and it makes you violate MVVM most likely.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa then how do i set the property dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class in order to access `elements` within.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181063/how-to-access-a-specific-item-in-a-listbox-with-datatemplate)!