# how to access controls in listview datatemplate in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to access a grid in a list-view data-template, but when using this code the program reaches the foreach loop and don't execute it

```
foreach (Grid firstgrid in Active_list.Items)
{
    var item = Active_list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(firstgrid);
    var ch = AllChildren(item);
    var tag = url;
    var control = (Grid)ch.First(c => c.Tag == tag);
    if (firstgrid.GetType() == typeof(Grid))
    {
        if ((String)firstgrid.Tag == url)
        {
            foreach (ProgressBar prg in firstgrid.Children)
            {
                if (prg.GetType() == typeof(ProgressBar))
                {
                    prg.IsIndeterminate = false;
                }
            }
            foreach (TextBlock txt in firstgrid.Children)
            {
                if (txt.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
                {
                    txt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code `Active_list.Items` won't give you any control but your actual data. If you want to access specific control in you list view, you need to go through your visual tree and find it manually. I think it's not a good practice to manually change controls inside list view...

But if you really want to do it this way I recommend you to check out this topic with similar question: [How to access a specific item in a Listbox with DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181063/how-to-access-a-specific-item-in-a-listbox-with-datatemplate)

Comment: in this question he access the control when the listbox is clicked, but i need to get all the controls in my listview.

Comment: I can't check it now, but I guess these controls should be in `Active_list.Children`. When you set a breakpoint just before the `foreach` loop, you can look what controls are there.

Comment: Active_list.Children not working when you can check it tell me

Comment: When you set a breakpoint and run your  app in debug mode, then the app will stop on the breakpoint. Then you can point mouse cursor on `Active_list` in code and VisualStudio will show you properties of it. Then you den expand them and browse to see what's inside.